# Convert triangleindices to Point3d, then display as lines

Tags: wpf, 3d

I import a model using the Helix3d toolkit. Next, I perform a hit-test on the 3Dmodel. ThenI get the MeshGeometry3D information from rayMeshResult.Meshit. Finally I get the vertex position information, and triangleIndices from the MeshGeometry3D. Now I clone the points from LinesVisual3D, and then I feed the triangleIndices/vertex info into the clone. Finally, I copy the clone's point data into LinesVisual3D.Points, and add the lines to my viewport.

As you can see from the picture at the link, not all of the edges of the cube are drawn, yet all of the points are there.

http://www.freeimagehosting.net/fhws5

```
GeometryModel3D hitgeo = rayMeshResult.ModelHit as GeometryModel3D;
MeshGeometry3D newGeom = rayMeshResult.MeshHit as MeshGeometry3D;
Point3DCollection srtpnt = modelLines.Points.Clone();

for (int i = 0; i < newGeom.TriangleIndices.Count; i ++)
{
    srtpnt.Add(newGeom.Positions[newGeom.TriangleIndices[i]]);
    textBlock4.Text += newGeom.Positions[newGeom.TriangleIndices[i]].ToString() + "\n";
}

modelLines.Points = srtpnt;
modelPoints.Points = srtpnt;

modelPoints.Color = Colors.Red;
modelPoints.Size = 15;

modelLines.Thickness = 6;
modelLines.Color = Colors.Blue;

MainViewport.ClearChildren();
MainViewport.Children.Add(modelLines);
MainViewport.Children.Add(modelPoints);
UpdateResultInfo(rayMeshResult);
```

Comment: The link to your image seems broken.